# How to change a certain value from an element saved inside an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I'm creating a table. Each row has individual values. I'm creating these rows in a for loop and save every row in an Array. Now lets say I want to change one value with the id = "number" in the row which is saved in `Row_Array[2]`. How do I achieve this with JavaScript or jQuery?

Here I create the rows and save them in my array

```js
var Row_Array = new Array (); 
var number_initiated_rows = 0; 


for (var i = 0; i <= finalnumber; i++)
            { 

            newrow = "<tr><td id = 'number'>"+i+"</td><td><input 
      class= 'segment' min= '0' type='number' value='"+lengthx+"'></td> </tr>"

            //in this Array I'm saving the rows 
                       Row_Array[number_initiated_rows] = newrow;
            number_initiated_rows++;


            $('#table').append(newrow);


                }
```

Now the table is created, but I want to change the "number" of `Row_Array[2]` to another value then "i". How do I achieve this?

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Comment: Make an array of the data you want to render, then render the data. When you want to change the data, change the array, then rerender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give ID (name + loop index) for each **td** attribute and update value by **td** ID

```js
var data = [{
  id: 0
}, {
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}];
var html = "";
data.forEach((element, i) => {
  html += "<td id='id" + i + "'>" + i + "</td>";
});
document.getElementById("table1").innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById("id2").innerHTML = "hai";
```

```html
<table id="table1">

</table>
```

Comment: Answers which explain code are more often upvoted than those that just present code without explanation...

Answer (score 0):

Use splice on the array. Refer [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)